# Что такое "рекурсивное программирование"?

Tags: теория

Почитал я оглавление от [книги 'Введение в рекурсивное программирование'](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/algorithms/978-5-97060-703-9/)

Но так и не понял что такое рекурсивное программирование.

Кроме того что это чуть меньше кода

```
// рекурсивная функция
int sum_first_natyrals(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return sum_first_natyrals(n-1) + n;
}
```

И чуть больше сложности.

```
// не рекурсивная функция
int sum_first_natyrals(int n)
{
    int s_f_n =0; 
     if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        for (int i = n; i <0; i--)
             s_f_n += i;
        return  s_f_n;
}
```

Также помню что на собеседованиях этому методу программирования уделяют внимание.

---

*Учитывая что по сути вызов функции  (не единичный, а частый ) лично по мне уже представляться как "рекурсия". Либо это маркетинговый ход типа "масла масленого"  либо как я видел на крекерах надпись : "подходит для употребления с хумусом и моцарелой". Намного маркетинговей звучит, в отличие от такого более точного написания : "подходит для употребления с гороховой кашей и сыром".*

Comment: Видать, вам стоит почитать саму книгу. Или какой-нибудь учебник по алгоритмам.

Comment: Рекурсия реально не применяется в жизни хотя бы потому, что при рекурсии программист не контролирует аппаратный стек. Так что чего там товарищ Мануэль Рубио-Санчес собрался рекурсивно программировать не очень понятно.

Comment: Рекурсия - это вполне конкретная техника, применяемая вживую. Она не имеет никакого отношения к частоте вызова. Вам следует почитать книгу, или учебник по алгоритмам - понятие же базовое, и непонятно, что именно в нем вам непонятно :)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 зависит от языка. В функциональных, вроде f#, поведение стека вполне предсказуемо, там рекурсия повсюду, даже в базовой библиотеке - никто не перебирает списки циклами. и, судя по упоминанию хвостовой рекурсии в оглавлении, книга именно про функциональщину.

Comment: Есть рекурсивные структуры данных. В частности, деревья. Для работы с ними рекурсии естественны и очень удобны.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Сережа быть "добрым" намного тяжелее чем быть "умным"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Некоторые алгоритмы запрограммированные рекурсивно в самом деле будут более изящны, нежели их итеративные аналоги.

А вот на практике к рекурсивным реализациям стоит подходить осторожно (и вовсе не из-за стека), поскольку такие программы обычно сложнее изменять при появлении новых требований к обрабатываемым данным.

Точнее, заранее надо тщательно планировать, как возможные изменения во внешних данных можно будет "протянуть" через внутренние структуры, используемые рекурсивными функциями. Особенно при наступлении аварийных случаев где-то внутри рекурсивных вызовов.

Comment: не вижу ответа на вопрос "что такое ...." (типа: решение проблемы, ссылаясь на само решение проблемы).

Comment: @jfs, вы правы. Напишите свой ответ

Comment: на такие вопросы ("что такое X", предполагая нулевые знания по X), [лучше на википедия отвечать](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), но если вы здесь хотите ответить,  то стоит хотя бы супер кратко тему раскрыть. А  то получается дискуссионный форум какой-то, а не Q&A сайт. Ваше право, если хотите сайт таким образом использовать.

Answer (score 3):

Рекурсивное программирование — это программирование с использованием рекурсий.

Рекурсия (в программировании) — это использование функций (методов), которые для выполнения заданной задачи ссылаются на самих себя.

Пример. Нужно раздробить глыбу льда для прохладительных напитков на куски не более 1,5 см. Решение с помощью рекурсии:

```
$желательный_размер_льда = 1.5см;
@итоговые_куски_льда = ();

функция дробить_лёд ($кусок_льда) {

   если ($кусок_льда <= $желательный_размер_льда) то {
      поместить $кусок_льда в @итоговые_куски_льда;
      выходим;
   }

   @куски_льда = выполнить_колотый_удар(кусок_льда);

   для каждого ($кусок из @куски_льда) {
       если ($кусок > $желательный_размер_льда) то {
           дробить_лёд($кусок);
       } иначе {
           поместить $кусок_льда в @итоговые_куски_льда;
       }
   }
}
```

Т.е. сначала мы применяем действие **дробить_лёд** к целой глыбе, потом к кускам поменьше, потом к их собственным кускам и так до тех пор, пока не получим куски размером не более 1,5 см. Эта *проверка* (в данном случае на размер куска) является **выходом из рекурсии** и является *обязательной*, в противном случае функция будет вызывать себя "*бесконечно*".